# Seeking vector data for wind speed and operating turbines in UK?

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I have been familiarising myself with QGIS and the free information Ordnance Survey provide. Though I'm struggling to find further data specific to my needs.

I want to produce a map plotting renewable energy in the UK (or at least operating wind turbines) against locations of operating data centres, preferably on a background of wind speeds.

Are there places where I access this data?

By so far I have seen only these sources:

- This website provides locations of data centres: https://www.datacentermap.com/
- This renewable energy: https://ukdataexplorer.com/renewables/
- This has wind speed but when I import it is all the same colour: https://www.renewables-atlas.info/

Comment: Increasing chances of finding the data are possible with [Open Data SE | Ask a question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: UK NOABL Wind Speed Database http://www.wind-power-program.com/UK_wind_speed_database.htm

Comment: Haven't you listed sources for all the data you want? Data centres and a wind turbines? What's wrong with them? How are you stuck now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you import a shapefile (or zipped shapefile) into QGis is just displays the data using a random color. So you need to style it and select a attribute to colour it in by and how you'd like the values mapped to colours.

[image]

The trick with the wind speed data is to read the documentation (boring though that is) - so looking in the included "Wind_attributes.txt" file gives us:

> Timescales
>
> An = Annual SP = Spring SU = Summer AU = Autumn WI = Winter
>
> JA = January FB = February MR = March AP = April MY = May JN = June JL
>   = July AG = August SE = September OC = October NV = November DC = December
>
> Heights
>
> 80 = 80 metres above sea surface 100 = 100 metres above sea surface
>
> Parameters
>
> WS = Mean Wind Speed recorded in metres per second (m/s)
>
> PD = Mean Wind Power Density calculated per square metre of rotor
>   swept area

If I choose to use a **Graduated** style I will get a choice of columns to map. Based on the above list  it looks like if I pick `an_ws_80m` I will be mapping Annual Wind Speed at 80m above sea level.

Pressing the classify button will apply the settings to the map. I find that the map looks better with **Jenks Natural Breaks** rather than **Equal Intervals** but your mileage may vary. I have also increased the number of classes.

[image]

Finally to make it look a little nicer I removed the black lines by setting the **Stroke style** to *No Pen*.

[image]

Comment: That's great thank you! Also, i was wondering is it possible to both graduate AND categorize information when bringing in a .csv?

Comment: Yes, first set up the categorize or graduated style how you want, then change the style to rule-based. Each category will be automatically converted to a rule. Select a rule and choose "refine selected rules" at the bottom of the style manager. There you have the option to add scales, categories or ranges.